# How not to include the information of the files appended to the log Tidlog file (indy) of a message

Tags: delphi, indy10

The log file (Indy) of an email in SMTP format includes the information of the attached files that are not necessary for my needs.

Adding information from attached files greatly increases the log file and causes me problems reading this information. I keep this file in a "blob" field of the database. Reading this field is causing me problems.
Do you have an example of a code that retains this information (other than the files attached)?

Answer (score 0):

The default `TIdLog...` components are meant to log whatever *raw data* is being transmitted/received over the socket connection, for purposes of debugging and replaying sessions. There are no real filtering capabilities.

If you don't want portions of the emails being logged, you will have to use `TIdLogEvent` or `TIdConnectionIntercept`, or derive a custom `TIdLog...` or `TIdConnectionIntercept...` based component, to parse the raw data yourself, essentially re-implementing the SMTP and RFC822 protocols so you can choose to log only what you want.